# constraining values to a range in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I can limit an array to values less than or greater than using individual values but how can I limit an array of values to a specific range.

Example snippet of code below:

```
arrayphase_sort=sortrows(arrayphase,4); %sort by phase in deg low to high
arrayphase_sort_limit_idx=arrayphase_sort(:,4)<45;% idx to limit array to phase angles under 45 degree
arrayphase_sort_limit=arrayphase_sort(arrayphase_sort_limit_idx,:); %limit array to phase angles under 45 degree
```

but I tried adding &>10 to see if I could get the array to show everything greater than 10 and less than 45 example below: (but I get an error)

```
arrayphase_sort_limit_idx=arrayphase_sort(:,4)<45**&>10**;
```

I know it's a syntax issues but I'm not sure the proper syntax.
Any idea the proper syntax to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
A = round(180 * rand(10, 10))
A(A > 10 & A < 45)
```

First line generates a 10x10 matrix of random data, the second line extracts numbers between 10 and 45.